# Linq groupBy, Sum and orderBy

Tags: c#, json, linq, sum

Still learning Linq here. So I've got a class that looks like this (comes from a db table):

```
class FundRaisingData
{
public double funds { get; set; }
public DateTime date { get; set; }
public string agentsGender { get; set; }
}
```

What I need to do is transform this to list of anonymous objects that looks something like this (it will be transformed and returned as JSON later ). I know this is not an anonymous object, but it will give you some idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
class groupedFunds
{
public string gender { get; set; }
public List<double> fundsRaised { get; set; }
}
```

So I need to figure out how I can sum the funds for each year in the right order (2010-2014).

Eventually it should look like this in JSON:

```
ListOfGroupedFunds[
{
"gender" : "Female",
"fundsRaised" : [2000, 2500, 3000]
},
{
"gender" : "Male",
"fundsRaised": [4300,2300,3100]
}
];
```

So fundsRaised[0] would correspond to 2012, fundsRaised[1] would correspond to 2013, etc. but not actually say "2013" anywhere in the object.

I've read a ton of articles today on Linq and searched through similar StackOverflow articles but I still just can't quite figure it out. Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be awesome.

-- Edit 2 (changing code more closely match solution) --

I think the code by Mike worked well, but because I'm not sure how many years there will be in advance I've modified it slightly:

```
var results = data.GroupBy(g=> Gender = g.agentsGender)
              .Select(g=> new 
                          { 
                             gender = g.Key  
                             years = g.GroupBy(y=> y.Date.Year)
                                      .OrderBy(y=> y.Key)
                                      .Select(y=> y.Sum(z=> z.funds))
                                      .ToArray()
                          })
              .ToArray();
```

Is there anything wrong about the above? It seems to work but I'm open to better solutions of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying for any number of years is just another sub `GroupBy()` in your gender group.

```
var results = data.GroupBy(g=> Gender = g.agentsGender)
                  .Select(g=> new 
                              { 
                                 gender = g.Key  
                                 years = g.GroupBy(y=> y.Date.Year)
                                          .OrderBy(y=> y.Key)
                                          .Select(y=> y.Sum(y.funds))
                                          .ToArray()
                              })
                  .ToArray();
```

Comment: How are is the index of each year's data guaranteed?

Comment: You just sort on your group key with `OrderBy()` so the earliest years  will be first.

Comment: What if one year has no data in the group?

Comment: Is that a requirement of the OP?

Comment: No it's not a requirement. I can (and will need to) pull that data out in a separate query. But it does in fact require that I pull the years out in order in a separate data structure.

Comment: Yes it is. "So fundsRaised[0] would correspond to 2012, fundsRaised[1] would correspond to 2013," If there is no data for 2012 then fundsRaised[0] would have 2013 in it.

Comment: Sorry the question seemed ambiguous Mike. Also, sorry I posted the edit above so late. It seems like Cam & I came to the modified solution at the same time (I've been editing for a while). It doesn't necessarily matter that fundsRaised[0] has 2013 or 2012 in it, but just that they are grouped according to the data that is (or isn't) available. in fact it doesn't even matter if it reads fundsRaised[0] corresponds to 2014, fundsRaised[1] corresponds to 2016 and fundsRaised[2] corresponds to 2017 etc. Missing values aren't really a concern. Also I missed that last OrderBy

Answer (score 0):

Thins LINQ statement will Group By Gender, then get the sum of funds per year as a List.

```
var query = from d in data
            group d by d.agentsGender into g
            select new { gender = g.Key, fundsRaised = new List<double> {
                g.Where(f => f.date.Year == 2012).Sum(f => f.funds),
                g.Where(f => f.date.Year == 2013).Sum(f => f.funds),
                g.Where(f => f.date.Year == 2014).Sum(f => f.funds),
            }};
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! What if I don't know how many years I'm going to have?

Comment: That gets way more complex, because year is inferred by position in the a fixed length array. If for example, your data had no data for year 2013, but did for 2012 & 2014, then a group by would return an only 2 elements. So basically in order to ensure a fixed array size, the years have to be specified in some way, because it can always be inferred from the data. If you don't specify the years in linq you'd have to do it somewhere. I hope that makes sense. If you could change your data structure to include year & sum, this wold be much simpler.

Comment: So you're saying create a data structure with year and sum in it already and then use a different operation to pull out the data that I'm looking for? I've been playing with it, and I think I may have found the solution I'm looking for thanks to your help. I'll post the code in the solution